# How to compile and run a Kotlin (.kt) file using the Terminal

Tags: kotlin, terminal, compilation, execution

I am new to Kotlin. Just figuring things out!

Answer (score 1):

Just run this on your terminal:

`kotlinc filename.kt -include-runtime -d filename.jar && java -jar filename.jar`